# how do I call a djago admin delete fuction

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to use the Django admin delete function to ensure that the corresponding quantity is deleted from the associated page when the delete function is clicked.

For example, I have a class called RestockModel. When I add a new Restock item, the restock quantity can be automatically added in the StockListModel. However, when I need to delete the Restock item, the quantity in StockListModel is not deleted immediately.

How can I call the django admin delete function to this statement?

Here is the code that how I made the quantity can be added when I create a new restock item:

```
class restockInfo(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ["product", "delivery_order_no","restock_quantity", "supplier_name", "created_date"]
readonly_fields = ["created_date"]
search_fields = ['created_date']

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    product = obj.product
    restock_quantity = obj.restock_quantity
    if restock_quantity and product.quantity_in_store:
        if restock_quantity >= 0:
            obj.product.quantity_in_store = product.quantity_in_store + restock_quantity
        # don't forget to save stock after change quantity
            obj.product.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully added!')
            super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid Quantity, Please Try Again!!!')
            return restockInfo
```

This is my restock models:

```
class restockList(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey("stockList", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
delivery_order_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
restock_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
supplier_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, editable=False)

class Meta:
    db_table = "restocklist"
```

and this is my stocklist models:

```
class stockList(models.Model):
product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
part_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
quantity_in_store = models.IntegerField(null=True)
location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
your_choices = (
    ('1', 'Available'),
    ('2', 'Unavailable'),
)
product_status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=your_choices, null=True)


def stock_image(self):
    return format_html('<img href="{0}" src="{0}" width="80" height="80" />'.format(self.product_image.url))
stock_image.short_description = 'Product Image'
stock_image.allow_tags = True

def __str__(self):
    return self.product_name
    #return "%s %s" % (self.product_name, self.quantity_in_store)

class Meta:
    db_table ="stocklist"
```

Comment: can you show how the models look like?

Comment: class restockList(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("stockList", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    delivery_order_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    restock_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    supplier_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "restocklist"

Comment: both models please

Comment: class stockList(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    part_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    quantity_in_store = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
       def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
        #return "%s %s" % (self.product_name, self.quantity_in_store)
   
 class Meta:
        db_table ="stocklist"